# python timer timeout value is too large

Tags: python, python-multithreading

so is the code for ban player.
but when is 1 year mean (31622400 sec) so it show error  timeout value is too large
i use python 3.8.1 64 bit window.
how to fix that?

```
if text.startswith("ban player for time/"):
    nickname = text.split('/')[1]
    timeForBan = text.split('/')[2]    
    TimeAfterBan = (datetime.datetime.now() + 
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(timeForBan)))
    BanPlayer(nickname, TimeAfterBan)
    timer = Timer(int(timeForBan), RemoveBanFromPlayer, [nickname])
    timer.start()
```

Comment: Even if it _would_ be possible, keeping timer-threads alive for **one year** is definitely not the right solution. A simple solution would be to register banned users with expiry-datetime in a file, then check this file once a day and create <24h-timers for removing the ban. To run the updating-script once a day you could use [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) for example.

Comment: @Darkonaut but if player have ban of 1 min i dont think he will wait 24h for remove ban

Comment: Well, that's up to you ;) But seriously, you don't need to keep _all_ banned players in such a file, only those with > 24h expiry time, for smaller intervals you can schedule a timer immediately.